# c++ how to use return value of function immediately in another function as reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have the following code to try to combine vectors by chaining a call to function `combine`. I'm getting error: `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<int> combine(vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2) {
    vector<int> v;
    for(int ele : v1) v.push_back(ele);
    for(int ele : v2) v.push_back(ele);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3};
    vector<int> v2 = {4,5,6};
    vector<int> v3 = {7,8,9};
    combine(v1, combine(v2, v3));
}
```

Why is this, and what is the correct workaround?

I am afraid that doing this might cause unnecessary copying:

```
vector<int> temp = combine(v2, v3);
combine(v1, temp);
```

Comment: You cannot bind a temporary value to a non constant reference.

Comment: You should just make `v1` and `v2` const. You never change them.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow will that be better performance than the way I did it? I'm just not sure what happens behind the scenes

Comment: The main difference is that with `const` it's actually legal C++ code. Speed wise the argument types are not the problem, the body of the function is.

Answer (score 2):

Your `combine()` function is returning a `vector` by value, which means it returns a temporary object that is destroyed as soon as the caller is done using it.  As such, the function is returning an rvalue, and an rvalue cannot bind to a reference to a *non-const* object, as you are trying to do, hence the error.

Make your function parameters be references to `const` objects instead.  An rvalue can bind to a `const` reference. And besides, your function is not modifying the input `vector`s, so they should be `const` anyway.

Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//                   \/                     \/
vector<int> combine(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2) {
    vector<int> v;

    // you should add this for good measure:
    // v.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());

    for(int ele : v1) v.push_back(ele);
    for(int ele : v2) v.push_back(ele);

    // alternatively:
    // v.insert(v.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end());
    // v.insert(v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());

    return v;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3};
    vector<int> v2 = {4,5,6};
    vector<int> v3 = {7,8,9};

    // now this will work as expected...
    vector<int> v4 = combine(v1, combine(v2, v3));

    for(int ele : v4) {
        cout << ele << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: I'm not sure there is much benefit, but `combine` could take `v1` by value, and use it instead of `v` for all of the heavy lifting. Maybe the compiler can do some slick eliding for us and eliminate some copy-work.

Comment: @user4581301 not likely, taking `v1` by value would pretty much require a copy be made. This is why move semantics were invented.

Answer (score 1):

Making the arguments to `combine` const solves the original problem:

```
vector<int> combine(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2)
```

But having to call combine on pairs of vectors is both inefficient and too much to type. Here is my take on this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>

// make a variadic function so all the combining can be done in one call     
template <typename T, typename... U>
requires (std::same_as<U , std::vector<T>> && ...)         // all U must be vectors of T
std::vector<T> combine(std::vector<T>&& v, U... vs) {      // allow move semantic for arguments
    std::vector<T> res(v.size() + (vs.size() + ...));      // make vector big enough to hold the result
    for(auto && ele : v) res.emplace_back(std::move(ele)); // copy/move first vector
    ([&res](auto && t) {                                   // copy/move the rest
        for(auto && ele : t) res.emplace_back(std::move(ele));
    }(vs), ...);
    return res;                                            // return result with copy elision
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> v3 = {7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> c = combine(v1, v2, v3);
}
```